# Angular with spring boot backend returning 404 on existing route after getting JWT

Tags: java, spring, angular, jwt

I'm trying to work out a simple web app with angular as the front end and Spring Boot as the back end. My pre-flight request succeeds and I receive a valid token, however when trying to make a subsequent request to a route I get a 404. When I try to curl the url I get a 500 with the message "Missing or invalid authorization header" which seems to me to be saying that the route does indeed exist and is listening, but something else is wrong.

First of all the Typescript. Here is my `login.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/index";
import { LoginService } from "../services/login.service";

@Component({
    selector: "login",
    templateUrl: "./login.component.html"
})

export class Login {
    private model = {"username": "", "password": ""};
    private currentUserName;

    constructor (private loginService: LoginService) {
        this.currentUserName = localStorage.getItem("currentUserName");
    }

    public onSubmit() {
        console.log("submitting");
        this.loginService.sendCredential(this.model).subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log(data);
                localStorage.setItem("token", data);
                console.log("Setting token");
                this.loginService.sendToken(localStorage.getItem("token")).subscribe(
                    data => {
                        this.currentUserName = this.model.username;
                        localStorage.setItem("currentUserName", this.model.username);
                        this.model.username = "";
                        this.model.password = "";
                    },
                    error => console.log(error)

                );
            },
            error => {
                console.log("oh no");
                console.log(error)
            }
        );
    }
}
```

And then my `LoginService`

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/index";

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    token: string;
    constructor (private http: HttpClient) {}

    public sendCredential(model): Observable<String> {
        const tokenUrlPreFlight = "http://localhost:8080/users/login/";
        const httpOptions: {} = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'ContentType': 'application/json'
            })
        };
        return this.http.post<String>(tokenUrlPreFlight, model, httpOptions);
    }

    public sendToken(token) {
        const tokenUrlPostFlight = "http://localhost:8080/rest/users/";
        console.log("Bearer " + token);

        const httpOptions: {} = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            })
        };

        return this.http.get(tokenUrlPostFlight, httpOptions);
    }

    public logout(): void {
        localStorage.setItem("token", "");
        localStorage.setItem("currentUserName", "");
        alert("You just logged out");
    }

    public checkLogin(): boolean {
        if(localStorage.getItem("currentUserName") != null && localStorage.getItem("currentUserName") != "" && localStorage.getItem("token") != null && localStorage.getItem("token") != "") {
            console.log(localStorage.getItem("currentUserName"));
            console.log(localStorage.getItem("token"));
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

And now for the java. First here is my entry point:

```
import com.acb.app.configuration.JwtFilter;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean jwtFilter() {
        final FilterRegistrationBean<JwtFilter> filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(new JwtFilter());
        filterRegistrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/rest/*");
        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

My `UserController.java`

```
import com.acb.app.model.User;
import io.jsonwebtoken.*;
import com.acb.maki.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("")
    public List<User> userIndex() {
        return userService.getAllUsers();
    }

    @GetMapping("{username}")
    public Optional<User> getUserByUsername(@RequestBody String username) {
        return userService.findByUsername(username);
    }

    @PostMapping("login")
    public String login(@RequestBody Map<String, String> json) throws ServletException {
        if(json.get("username") == null || json.get("password") == null) {
            throw new ServletException("Please fill in username and password");
        }

        final String username = json.get("username");
        final String password = json.get("password");

        Optional<User> optionalUser = userService.findByUsername(username);
        if(!optionalUser.isPresent()) {
            throw new ServletException("Username not found");
        }

        User user = optionalUser.get();

        if(!password.equals(user.getPassword())) {
            throw new ServletException("Invalid login. Please check username and password");
        }
        final String response = Jwts.builder().setSubject(username).claim("roles", "user").setIssuedAt(new Date()).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "secretKey").compact();
        final String jsonResponse = String.format("\"%s\"", response);

        System.out.println(jsonResponse);
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    @PostMapping(value="/register")
    public User register(@RequestBody User user) {
        return userService.save(user);
    }
}
```

And last but not least my `JwtFilter.java`

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.*;
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;



public class JwtFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if ("OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        } else {
            if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                throw new ServletException("Missing or invalid authorization header");
            }

            final String token = authHeader.substring(7);

            try {
                final JwtParser jwtParser = Jwts.parser();
                final Jws<Claims> claimsJws = jwtParser.setSigningKey("secretKey").parseClaimsJws(token);
                final Claims claims = claimsJws.getBody();
                request.setAttribute("claims", claims);
            } catch (final SignatureException e) {
                throw new ServletException("Invalid token.");
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```

I am very aware of the bad practices here with comparing plain text passwords, etc. I'm just trying to get this to work for the time being. The token is correctly generated and returned. The token is also set correctly to local storage, but upon making the get request to the `/rest/users` route a 404 is returned. There are no errors on the java side.

Comment: You're sending a request to /rest/users. Your service is mapped to /users. As simple as that.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes I can see that, however changing my service to be mapped to /rest/users/ causes a blocked request due to potential cross site scripting. So I'm not really sure how to protect my other routes then, when my filter is active for /rest/* patterns

Comment: Note that you wouldn't have to mess with CORS if you simply configured Angular-CLI's ng serve to act as a reverse proxy for your Spring boot backend. That would also allow you to remove all your hard-coded `http://localhost:8080` from your source code.

Comment: Absolutely! That is something that is on my list, however I'm trying to follow along with a slightly outdated tutorial at the moment just trying to get a bit of a feel for spring and angular. The whole thing will have to go through a bit of an upgrade in the near future. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

So as I expected, I am indeed an idiot. As the user mentioned above my service maps to `/users/` and what I needed is the protected version `/rest/users`. So next to my UserController I created `UserResource.java` which looks like so:

```
import com.acb.app.model.User;
import com.acb.app.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class UserResource {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/users")
    public List<User> findAllUsers() {
        return userService.getAllUsers();
    }
}
```

And this makes use of the JwtFilter and allows me to protect my routes. Hopefully this will be helpful to someone else.